# Deploying SQLite database with Delphi application on Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, delphi, firemonkey

I'm having some trouble with adding SQLite database into my Android application written in Delphi. First, I have added the database file into the project manager and in deployment manager changed its `Remote Path` to `.\assets\internal\`. Then I have added the following code into `FDConnection` `BeforeConnect` event. The code is:

```
begin
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  MissiledbConnection.Params.Values['ColumnMetadataSupported'] := 'False';
  MissiledbConnection.Params.Values['Database'] :=
      TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'MissileDB.db');
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Despite that, I'm still getting this error while trying to compile Android version of my application:
`[FireDAC][Stan][Def]-254. Definition [MissileDB.db] is not found in []`

When I compile my application under Windows, everything works perfectly fine. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong, since every tutorial I've found only mentions the Deployment manager and the event code, which I implemented as I shown.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens if you delete the application from the device and redeploy?

Comment: Nothing changes, both with internal and external paths.

Comment: You say you get the error when 'trying to compile'. This makes no sense as the compiler has no reason to try to open the database. Do you mean the error occurs when you try to run the application? If that is the case, it means that the connection is set to active at design time, and the application, on it's first run, is opening the connection before the Database param has been set.

Answer (score 0):

I applied to "TPath.GetHomePath" and the application started. Resource 'assets/internal' places the database in this directory by default. It is inaccessible from the outside. How to put deploy to a different but public or shared directory, unfortunately, I do not know.
regards AK